# jquery create prototype from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I would like to cheat a little bit when creating prototypes

for example

```
var person = {
   name: 'John',
   age: 110,
   gender: 'm',
   ...
};

var employee = new Person(person);

function Person(args) {
   $.each(args, function(key, value) {
      this[key] = value; // Cannot create property 'key' on number
   });
}

console.log(employee.age);
```

In PHP this can be done like

```
function __construct() {
    $args = func_get_arg(0);            
    foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem here. What do you expect us to do? What kind of solution that you are expecting?

Comment: Well assigning this[key] = value is not working.
I would like to create a Person out of object instead of creating something like this:

var employee = new Person(person.name, person.age, person.gender, ...);
and
function Person(name, age, gender, ...) this.name = name etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem on your jQuery code is that 'this' is actually in the jquery each scope, so to actually prototype your new instance you need to do this:

```
function Person(args) {
    var _this = this;
   $.each(args, function(key, value) {
      _this[key] = value;
   });
}
```

You can also achieve this without using jQuery:

```
 function Person(args) {
    for(var key in args){
        this[key] = args[key];
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

the problem is "this" refers to the each function and not the actual Person
you can change it to arrow function an it will work

```js
var person = {
   name: 'John',
   age: 110,
   gender: 'm',
   ...
};

var employee = new Person(person);

function Person(args) {
   $.each(args, (key, value) => { //changed to arrow function to keep this in the same scope
      this[key] = value; // Cannot create property 'key' on number
   });
}

console.log(employee.age);
```

Comment: Might add that the difference between this and the OP's PHP version is that the PHP version uses a loop instead of a callback function (so no scoping issue).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Comment: Note that arrow functions might cause compatibility issues: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: Or just use `bind(this)` 
`$.each(args, function(key, value) { this[key] = value; }.bind(this));`

Answer (score 1):

Use `bind` for getting the right scope

```
function Person(args) {
   $.each(args, function(key, value) {
      this[key] = value; 
   }.bind(this)); //Use bind for getting the right scope
}
```